# Python multiprocessing loop stops always for certain threads

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to accelarte data loading and interpolation by using multithreading. So far my code seems to work. The only problem is that it always runs up to the given number of procs.
Say my files are 100. If I run the script with 24 cores only 24 files are being loaded, but I need to keep going on up to 100. What am I missing here?

```
        print ('Number of overall VTK Files: ' + str(len(vtkArray)))
    def dataoperator(N,i,vtkArray,field):
        #for i in range(N-100,N):
        print ("Loading data " +str(vtkArray[i,1] + ' index :' + str(i)))
        points, cells, point_data, cell_data, field_data = meshio.read(ID +str(vtkArray[i,1]))
        x,y,z=np.transpose(points)
        print ("\t Interpolating data " +str(vtkArray[i,1] + ' index :' + str(i)))
        from scipy.interpolate import griddata
        if (scalar=='p'):
            p = np.transpose(point_data['p'])
            pi= griddata((x, y, z), p, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
            field[i,:,:,:]= pi
        else:
            u,v,w = np.transpose(point_data['subtract(U,U_bf)'])
            if (scalar=='u'):
                ui= griddata((x, y, z), u, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
                field[i,:,:,:]= ui
            elif (scalar=='v'):
                vi= griddata((x, y, z), v, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
                field[i,:,:,:]= vi
            else:
                wi = griddata((x, y, z), w, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
                field[i,:,:,:]= wi
        del points, cells, point_data, cell_data, field_data


    import multiprocessing
    jobs = []
    for i in range(0, procs):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=dataoperator,args=(N, i, vtkArray,field))
        jobs.append(process)

        # Start the processes 
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

        # Ensure all of the processes have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what your issue is, since your example does not run as it is written. But what is the value of `procs`? Maybe this value is set to the number of cores?

Comment: I'm not an expert in multiprocessing, but I think you are setting only one file to each core. So if you have 24 cores, you only compute 24 files. You should set a range of files to each core, like 4 or 5 files per core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `procs` processes are created, which call `dataoperator` exactly once with arguments `(N, i, vtkArray,field)`. Index `i` never will be larger equal `procs`.

Rewrite your code such that it makes use of queues: (I assume here that the `vtkArray` contains the 100 different cases).

```
# Assuming python3.    
from queue import Empty as EmptyException

resultQueue = multiprocessing.Queue() # to return data from your workers
taskQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
processes = []

def _worker(taskQueue, resultQueue, N, vtkArray, field):
    while True:
        try:
            # Block maximally 0.1s before EmptyException is thrown.
            i = taskQueue.get(timeout=0.1)
            ret = dataoperator(N, i, vtkArray, field)
            resultQueue.put(ret)
        except EmptyException:
            # Stop the loop.
            break

for i in range(len(vtkArray)):
    taskQueue.put(i)

for i in range(procs):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=_worker,
                                      args=(taskQueue, resultQueue, N, vtkArray, field),
                                      name="process%03d" % i)
    process.start()
    processes.append(process)

for p in processes:
    p.join()

try:
    rets = []
    while True:
        rets.append(resultQueue.get(block=False))
except EmptyException:
    pass
```

I haven't tested this code, just use it as a starting point. I highly recommend to read the documentation of the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) module. (I also recommend to use contexts, but this is another story.)

Comment: thanks normanius for your answer, i rewrote my code as you suggested and it seems to run besides I am not able to collect the results of ret with resultQueue.get. For clarification I would like to mention my purpose in the next post

Answer (score 0):

Due to the help of normanius I was able to setup loading and interpolating multiple files properly, besides I am still not able to collect the data with resultQueue.get(). The list is always empty, allthough a print statement in the _workers function of ret give results:

For clarification again my purpose:

1) Setting up a multidimensional array (gobally defined) `field=np.zeros([N,nx,ny,nz]) where`N=len(vtkArray) and vtkArray just a list of files (up to 100) to work on, nx,ny,nz number of nodes for interpolating

2) dataoperator() is function which loads and interpolate the data, now with multiprocessing, where index i corresponds to the index of processor and at which line to put the loaded data for multidimensional array field.

3) Code suggested from normanius seems to work fine, since a print statement of ret in the _workers function shows the correct results, processwise for each

4) Anyway, it is still not possible for me to receive the completely "filled" multidimensional array with the resultQueue.get() function. Is it also possible to return again, a multidimensional array or do I habe to use rets=[] as a list.

Thanks in advance for any help,

```
    ###################################################
     #Loading all vtk files and saving to multidim array
    ###################################################
    def dataoperator(i,vtkArray,nx,ny,nz,x0,x1,y0,y1,z0,z1,scalar):
        xi = np.linspace(x0,x1,nx,endpoint=True)
        yi = np.linspace(y0,y1,ny,endpoint=True)
        zi = np.linspace(z0,z1,nz,endpoint=True)
        yy,xx,zz=np.meshgrid(yi,xi,zi)

        #Generate MultiDimensional array
        vtkArrayString=[str(x) for x in vtkArray[:,1]]
        print ("Loading data " +str(prefix) + str(vtkArrayString[i])+' with index ' + str(i))
        points, cells, point_data, cell_data, field_data = meshio.read('./VTK/' +str(vtkArrayString[i]))
        #points, point_data=loaddata(vtkArrayString,i)

        x,y,z=np.transpose(points)
        print ("\t Interpolating data " +str(vtkArrayString[i]))
        from scipy.interpolate import griddata
        if (scalar=='p'):
            p = np.transpose(point_data['p'])
            pi= griddata((x, y, z), p, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
            field[i,:,:,:]= pi
        else:
            u,v,w = np.transpose(point_data['subtract(U,U_bf)'])
            if (scalar=='u'):
                ui= griddata((x, y, z), u, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
                field[i,:,:,:]= ui
            elif (scalar=='v'):
                vi= griddata((x, y, z), v, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
                field[i,:,:,:]= vi
            else:
                wi = griddata((x, y, z), w, (xx, yy, zz), method='nearest')
                field[i,:,:,:]= wi
        #return field, vtkArray
        print ("\t Finished Interpolating data " +str(vtkArrayString[i]))
        return field 

    import multiprocessing
    from queue import Empty as EmptyException


    resultQueue = multiprocessing.Queue() # to return data from your workers
    taskQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    processes = []

    def _worker(taskQueue, resultQueue, i, vtkArray):
        try:
            # Block maximally 0.1s before EmptyException is thrown.
            i = taskQueue.get(timeout=0.1)
            ret  = dataoperator(i,vtkArray,nx,ny,nz,x0,x1,y0,y1,z0,z1,scalar)
            print (ret)
            resultQueue.put(ret)
        except EmptyException:
            # Idle action, if needed.
            pass

    for i in range(steps):
        taskQueue.put(i)

    for i in range(procs):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=_worker,
                                          args=(taskQueue, resultQueue, i, vtkArray),
                                          name="process%03d" % i)
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)

    #ret2=np.zeros([N,nx,ny,nz])
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    try:
        rets = []
        while True:
            rets.append(resultQueue.get(block=False))
            print (rets)
    except EmptyException:
        pass
    print(rets)
    field=np.array(rets)
    print(field)
```

Comment: Is this a debugging request? Can I forward my bank account for the salary? :)

Comment: Note that I updated my answer because the `_worker` was not looping over the taskQueue until all tasks are consumed. Doubt that this will have an effect on your problem that you cannot send the results to the main process.

Comment: IIRC there are certain requirements regarding the type objects that can be sent through a queue (the object needs to picklable). Have you tried to send simple objects like strings? For me, the code works.